# how define derived class in header file and definition in a cpp file with method virtual

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to define a derived class in a header file and the definition of it in a cpp file but i have errors

my project files

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AmericanPerson.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    AmericanPerson joe("Joe");
    return 0;
}
```

human.h

```
#ifndef HUMAN_H__
#define HUMAN_H__

#include "definiciones.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Human
{
    protected:
        string nameC;
    public:
        Human(const string & name);

        virtual void talkTo(const Human & person) const;
        string name() const;
};

#endif
```

Human.cpp

```
#include "human.h"

Human::Human(const string & name) : nameC(name){}

string Human::name() const
{
    return nameC;
}
```

AmericanPerson.h

```
#ifndef AMERICANPERSON_H__
#define AMERICANPERSON_H__

#include "human.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class AmericanPerson : public Human
{
    public:
        AmericanPerson(const string & name);
};

#endif
```

AmericanPerson.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AmericanPerson.h"


AmericanPerson::AmericanPerson(const string & name) : Human(name)
{
}

//virtual method inherited from the base class Human

void AmericanPerson::talkTo(const Human & person) const //override ? 
{
    cout<< nameC << "dice: Hello " << person.name() << endl;
}
```

definiciones.h

```
#ifndef DEFINICIONES_H__
#define DEFINICIONES_H__

class Human;
class AmericanPerson;
class MexicanPerson;

#endif
```

to run the code gives me an error [Error] not 'void AmericanPerson :: talkto (const Human &) const' Declared in class member function 'AmericanPerson'

it can also be failures

thanks for your time

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message? You didn't declare a function called `talkto` in the definition of `AmericanPerson`, yet you're giving it a function body.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the problem was the definition in the .cpp file

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare a virtual override like you would any other class member function:

```
class AmericanPerson : public Human
{
    public:
        AmericanPerson(const string & name);
        void talkTo(const Human & person) const override;
};
```

Comment: thanks, That solved my problem but I figured emerged as more :) , human.h undefined reference to `vtable for Human'

Comment: thank you very much, and I solved the problem, I had forgotten to define the method talkto in Human.cpp